# problema de java: JFrames y clases entre dos archivos

Tags: java, clase, jframe

dispongo de dos archivos.
1 para hacer un jframe y otro para hacer el Toolbar, pero soy incapaz de añadir uno al otro.

```
package app;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculator
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Header cabecera = new Header();
        cabecera.cabezon();
        /* 1 */
        JFrame a = new JFrame("Calculator");
        a.setSize(800,800);
        a.setLayout(null);
        a.setVisible(true);



    }

}
```

y este seria el segundo archivo

```
package app;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;

class Header 
{
    public void cabezon() 
    {  
        JToolBar menuGrid = new JToolBar();
        JButton btn1_menuGrid = new JButton("File");
        JButton btn2_menuGrid = new JButton("View");
        JButton btn3_menuGrid = new JButton("About");
        menuGrid.add(btn1_menuGrid);
        menuGrid.add(btn2_menuGrid);
        menuGrid.add(btn3_menuGrid);
      }
}
```

seguramente sea una tonteria pero por ahora el error es este y no lo entiendo:
java Calculator.java

> Calculator.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
> Header cabecera = new Header();
> ^   symbol:   class Header   location: class Calculator Calculator.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
> Header cabecera = new Header();
> ^   symbol:   class Header   location: class Calculator 2 errors error: compilation failedd

Gracias por las respuestas

Comment: ¿Usas algún IDE?

Comment: Hola, probablemente estes compilando mal las clases, prueba con: **javac Calculator.java Header.java**.

Answer (score 1):

Si queres agregar el JToolBar en el JFrame, entonces no tienes solo un error si no dos. \

El error que te aparece es por que tanto la clase `Calculator` como la `Header` estan en diferentes paquetes y no has agregado la clave `public` en la clase Header para poder acceder a esta desde otro paquete.

Al hacer que la clase no sea publica, esta solo puede ser accedida desde el mismo paquete donde se encuentra. Es decir, se puede acceder desde otra clase siempre y cuando estén en el mismo paquete para poder utilizarla.

En otras palabras, debes modificar la clase Header para hacerla publica

```
public class Header {}
```

De esa manera podrías instanciar la clase desde otro paquete.

---

Por otro lado, también está el problema de que la clase Header no es un JToolBar, por lo que no podrás hacer un `add(cabecera)` en el JFrame.

Para agregar el `JToolBar` a la instancia del `JFrame`, la clase `Header` debe heredar de JToolBar, o proporcionar alguna forma para acceder a el JToolBar desde fuera de la clase. Por ejemplo, los métodos getter.

La primera opcion que te mencione se puede hacer de esta manera

```
public class Header extends JToolBar {

    public Header() {
        JButton btn1_menuGrid = new JButton("File");
        add(btn1_menuGrud);
        
        // aquí los demas botones
    }

}
```

Ahora podrías agregar la instancia de Header en el JFrame ya que al heredar de JToolBar se considera un componente. Y en el método `main` harías esto:

```
Header header = new Header();
a.add(header);
```

---

La otra forma sería proporcionar métodos getter para acceder a el JToolBar que has creado internamente con el método `cabezon()`. Para esto deberías cambiar un poco el como se crea el JToolBar internamente para hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Header  {

    private JToolBar menuGrid;
    private JButton fileButton;
    
    public Header() {
        menuGrid = new JToolBar();
        
        fileButton = new JButton("File");
        menuGrid.add(fileButton);
        
        // aqui los demas botones.
    }

    public JToolBar getMenuGrid() {
        return menuGrid;
    }
    
    public JButton getFileButton() {
        return fileButton;
    }

}
```

Y para agregar el JToolBar sería así:

```
Header header = new Header();
a.add(header.getMenuGrid());
```

Lo mas rápido y simple siempre será heredar y agregar como en la primera opción que te mencione, pero siempre necesitarás acceder a los diferentes botones del JToolBar proporcionando métodos getters. Entonces ya sea que heredes o que instancies deberás utilizar métodos getters.